# Is it possible to create a texture from a single mipmap level of another?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, textures, glsl

I have a shader that draws a texture, and I have the constraint that I cannot change this shader. It has a hardcoded bias of 0 passed to texture2D. I would like to draw the nth mipmap of a texture using this shader. i.e., I would like to have some texture bound to the input to this shader for which level 0 corresponds to level n of my original texture.

Is there any (inexpensive, preferably) way to do this?

Comment: What OpenGL version are you targeting? In desktop GL, there is [GL_ARB_texture_view](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_view.txt) providing exactly what you want. However, you tagged this as opengl-es, and this feature is not available in GLES.

Comment: Yes, I'm targeting ES 2.0. Sorry for not specifying. That's a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES 3.0 and later, you can restrict sampling to a range of levels by setting the sampling parameters accordingly. For example, to restrict sampling to only *level*, use:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, level);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, level);
```

These parameters are not available in ES 2.0. I don't think there's a good way to do this in ES 2.0 without creating a copy of the texture.

Note that using *bias* in the GLSL code does not mean that a fixed mipmap level is used. It **adds** the bias to the calculated level of detail. So a *bias* of 0.0 is the same as not providing a bias at all.

Comment: Is that distinction meaningful on ES 2.0 if there is no way for the base level to be anything other than 0? Or do you mean that the calculated level is not necessarily 0? If I draw a texture for which I've generated mipmaps and set the minimization filter appropriately into a rectangle that's half the texture's size, will the first mipmap level be used?